# Does Doctrine Orm cause performance issue?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my company we work with Symfony framework, but for Doctrine they says: "we will not use Doctrine because of performance issue with tons of data".

Are they right? If not, give me arguments to convince them they are wrong.

Comment: What have you done to test? Have you done any profiling?

Comment: ORMs always have overhead, but the benefits can outweigh those costs. Note that I say "can", not "do". Like everything else in computer science, this is about a tradeoff. Your team appears to have decided it's not a good tradeoff. We don't know your performance goals, how you're using your database, which database you're using, how much data there is… how can we possibly answer your question? You should be asking your _team_ why they've decided not to use Doctrine, not asking us to convince them they're wrong. Do they have data to back it up, or is it an uninformed decision?

Comment: This is really not a good fit for stackoverflow.  Look in the community section of the docs to see the chat board for doctrine.  But basically, if your apps are pretty much boilerplate CRUD apps then the ORM works well.  The problem is on the read side.  By default you always get complete objects which can slow things up if you only need a few columns.  There are work around but at then end of the day, custom sql queries (using the Doctrine DBAL layer) start to look very attractive.

Answer (score 0):

You can say the same about frameworks, Symfony is bigger and slower than simple php script, but  there are advantages that compensate possible performance loss.

And performance...  it's a difficult topic, but IMHO it's all about developer who is using framework. That's the reason why symfony provides debug bar - to see what is happening in app (if you see too many queries to db or strange db response time you can pinpoint and solve issue - before it's become a problem)

About Doctrine - search for Marco Pivetta and his speeches about Doctrine 
(for example  https://vimeo.com/134178140 )

Personally I never met a situation that Doctrine can't handle (especially with second level cache)